# What is the difference between config.action_mailer.smtp_settings and ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I set up an Exchange compatible mail server in a RoR application. I used the following setup in `development.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => 'mail.server.com',
  :port                 => 5870,
  :user_name            => 'username',
  :password             => 'password',
  :authentication       => :login
}
```

This setup does not work, I get `Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 504 Unrecognized authentication type.`

However if I apply the exact same configuration in `environment.rb`, it works perfectly:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => 'mail.server.com',
  :port                 => 5870,
  :user_name            => 'username',
  :password             => 'password',
  :authentication       => :login  
}
```

Why is this? Shouldn't `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings` set the same settings? Is this a bug? Does it have a reason?

I tried it with Gmail as [told here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail), and it **works**, so smtp_settings does have effect on the mailer, but it seems to me like not all the options count/work.

Answer (score 4):

`config.action_mailer.smtp_settings` forwards the settings to `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings`.

However, the main difference is that the former is an environment-specific setting while the second one is a global setting.

In other word, you should be sure to set `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings` in the proper environment file to apply the settings. If you want to use the settings in production, for example, add the assignment in the `config/environments/production.rb` file. Likewise, if you want the settings to be applied to the entire project, set them in `config/application.rb`.

Comment: I set up the configuration for development mode in `development.rb` but it did not forward the settings. The two seems not to be the same - this is what my question is about. You mean this is a bug?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem, the config.action_mailer.smtp_settings did not work, but every configuration was proper.

Finally i figured out, that a Rails extension overrides the ActionMailer::Base settings in the initializer phase... 
So investigate all your code and all the 3rd party codes (!), extensions, modules, etc. there should be the problem!

Comment: What extension was overwriting it?  I'm having a similar issue.